# How to retrieve all attributes of an anytree Node?

Tags: python, tree, anytree

For an [`anytree`](https://anytree.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) `Node`, how can I get all the attributes and their values?

For example, if I do:

```
>>> from anytree import Node
>>> root = Node("root")
>>> s0 = Node("sub0", parent=root, foo="10", bar="ggg")
```

how can I get something like `[("foo", "10"), ("bar", "ggg")]`?

I can think of a route via the following:

```
>>> s1=Node("dummy", parent=root)
>>> set(dir(s0))-set(dir(s1))
{'foo', 'bar'}
```

but I hope there is a more concise way.

Comment: The documentation you link to includes a list of all of a `Node`'s methods, which doesn't include what you're asking for. As you already know, you can use `dir` to get all of the attribute names (then e.g. `getattr` to access their values) but that will include some you don't consider relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working in your case:

```
s0.__dict__.items()
```

However, beware that this method relies on the inner implementation of `anytree` (and it's always a bad idea to rely on a specific implementation). Also, the `__dict__` attribute contains also the name, parent and (optionally) children (and you might want to get rid of these).

```
[(k, v) for k, v in s0.__dict__.items() if k not in ('name', 'parent', 'children')]
```